# C++ - Avoiding multiple inheritance when using pure abstract classes

Tags: c++, oop

I want to provide a stable API for a library I've written by providing a set of pure abstract classes.

Consider the following class hierarchy:

```
//Note: Destructors left out for readability

struct IBase{
    virtual void something() = 0;
}
struct IDerivedA : public IBase{
    virtual void another() = 0;
}
struct IDerivedB : public IBase{
    virtual void another(int a) = 0;
}
```

There will be multiple implementations for these interfaces. To write an implementation, I would do:

```
struct Base : public IBase{
    int x; //x is required to implement something()
    virtual void something();
}
struct DerivedA : public IDerivedA, public Base{
    virtual void another();
}
struct DerivedB : public IDerivedB, public Base{
    virtual void another(int a);
}
```

This leads to the dreaded diamond problem, for which I see the following solutions:

1. Virtually inherit `IBase` in both `IDerivedA` and `IDerivedB` and just use multiple inheritance
2. Don't use `Base` at all and instead forward the calls to a helper class to avoid code duplication

Something like:

```
struct Base{
    int x; //x is required to implement somethingImpl()
    void somethingImpl();
}
struct DerivedA : public IDerivedA{
    virtual void something(){ b.somethingImpl(); };
    virtual void another();

    private:
        Base b;
}
struct DerivedB : public IDerivedB{
    virtual void something(){ b.somethingImpl(); };
    virtual void another(int a);

    private:
        Base b;
}
```

In case of 1), virtual inheritance would be required every time I use inheritance in the API layer.
In case of 2), I would need to wrap `Base` for every implementation class, which leads to code bloat.

I believe that there might be something fundamentally wrong in the design. Is there a general best practice for this specific case?

Comment: My advise would be go for option 1.

Comment: It seems to me you want to multiply inherit different interfaces without multiply inheriting them.

Comment: If `IBase` and `IDerivedA/B` are all pure abstract classes, do the derived interfaces really need to inherit from the base interface? Just a thought for design.

Comment: @super Interesting thought. In this case, `IBase`is there for polymorphism. The caller shall be able to allocate a  std::vector<IBase*>.

Comment: I think this may be relevant from the `CppCoreGuidelines` https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#c129-when-designing-a-class-hierarchy-distinguish-between-implementation-inheritance-and-interface-inheritance

Comment: @Galik If I understood it correctly, then no virtual inheritance is needed because interfaces do not hold any data members/implementation details? The class hierarchy in the article is similar to the hierarchy provided in the question, yet no virtual inheritance is used.

Comment: @user3067395 -- yes and no. If you don't use virtual inheritance you lose direct conversions from the derived types to the base type. So with `void f(IBase*); DerivedB db; f(&db);`, the call to `f` is ambiguous because there are multiple versions of `iBase` in the `db` object. With virtual inheritance the call is okay.